# Add a css class to an element if the element has a certain text via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add the class `.active-trail` to an `li` element if the `li` element has a link (`a`) as a child element containing the word "Help".

Example:

```
<li class="last expanded dropdown">

  <a href="/test1" title="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data toggle="dropdown">
    Help <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

</li>

<li class="last expanded dropdown">

  <a href="/test1" title="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data toggle="dropdown">
    Contact <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

</li>
```

In the example above, I would like to add the class `active-trail` to the first `li` like so:

```
<li class="last expanded dropdown active-trail">

  <a href="/test1" title="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data toggle="dropdown">
    Help <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

</li>

<li class="last expanded dropdown">

  <a href="/test1" title="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data toggle="dropdown">
    Contact <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

</li>
```

Is this possible through javascript/jQuery, and if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this -

```
$('a').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().indexOf('Help') > -1;
}).closest('li').addClass('active-trail');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li a').each(function() {
    if( $(this).text().toLowerCase().search('Help') >= 0 ) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active-trail')
    }
})
```

Edit: I like Mohammad's solution better, but this should work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('li a'),function() {
    if ($(this).text.indexOf('Help') > -1) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active-trail');
    }
});
```